# Best way to allowing users to specify what attributes are available to public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

In one of my tables (sellers), all the fields requires permission from the user for others (registered or non-registered) to see.  I could go through and create an associated column for each column, ex. (column1, column1_privacy, column2, column2_privacy).  However, this seems redundant and bad design.

Is there a more elegant solution for this in Rails?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: one option would be to serialize everything in one single column but it's not that a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it redundant or bad design. If you want per-column access control then somewhere you're going to need one flag per column; you can pack all those flags into one serialized structure but then you'd be fighting against your relational database:

- What happens to your serialized ACLs when you add or remove a column? Do you regenerate them all or do you just accumulate cruft?
- What happens if you need to include the flags in a query? You're going to have a hard time unpacking your packed flag-blob in SQL and doing the unpacking in Ruby could be very expensive.

You could use a separate EAV-style table that contains column names but you'd still have to clean it as you add and remove columns. And querying with an EAV table tends to turn into an ugly mess quite quickly.

One flag-column for each access controlled column is easy to set up, easy to query, easy to edit, easy to automatically build forms for, and makes it easy to not make a mess in your database. The extra columns may make your tables a little on the wide side but I wouldn't worry about that too much.

The extra columns make it easy to extract the displayable information from your model:

```
def viewable_parts
  %w{column1 column2 column3}.each_with_object({}) do |col, h|
    h[col] = self.send(col) if(self.send(col + '_privacy')
  end
end
```

Then you can say things like this in your controller:

```
@display_info = model.viewable_parts
```

and your views don't have to worry too much about the access control, they can just show what's in the Hash. This trick can, of course, be used with the other implementations but it is dead easy if you use your "privacy column" idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a associated model named `SharedColumn`

```
rails g scaffold SharedColumn name:string, seller_id:integer
```

Seller:

```
has_many :shared_columns
```

SharedColumn

```
belongs_to :seller
```

Then you may use the `column_names`method for iteration of a list of checkboxes like this

Controller

```
@blacklisted_columns = [id, other_non_pubic_column]
```

View

```
<% Seller.column_names.each do |column_name| %>
     <% unless @blacklisted_columns.include?(column_name) %>
          #Generate your checkboxes and labels here
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```